# How to add Mixed mode and Multi axis chart in Only Office

Tags: onlyoffice

I am trying to add Mixed mode and Multi axis chart in **Only Office document server API** using plugin for Document, Spreadsheet and Presentation

```
    Api.CreateChart("bar3D", [[200, 240, 280],[250, 260, 280]], 
                             ["Projected Revenue", "Estimated Costs"], 
                             [2014, 2015, 2016], 4051300, 2347595, 24);
```

But i am not able to figure out.

please guide me on how i can add mixed chart of line and bar series and multiple axis in it.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot create files with multi axis charts using as they aren't supported by current version of ONLYOFFICE. In case you are interested in any kind of custom development feel free to contact the development team at support@onlyoffice.com

Comment: thanks @ibnpetr for quick comment. I contacted the sales team and they come up with the same as you suggested.